# Java - How to get XML contents in web

Tags: java, xml

I am creating a Java application. On the first run, my application will download required Java library and some images. My friend helps me to manage my files server. He creates an XML file that contains all the information about the required file.

Here is some part of the XML file

```
    <Files>
        <Url>lib/lwjgl.jar</Url>
        <DareCreated>2013-04-30T09:25:54.000Z</DateCreated>
        <Size>2389</Size>
    </Files>

    <Files>
        <Url>img/Icon.png</Url>
        <DateCreated>2013-05-21T12:26:15.000Z</DateCreated>
        <Size>56</Size>
    </Files>
```

I want my Java application to get the contents of the XML files for example `<Url>XXX/XXX.jar</Url>`. Then, my application will download the files from my web server.

The Url of my files will be like this, www.xxx.com/XML/ + the content of `<Url>X</Url>` in the XML file.

For example, www.xxx.com/XML/img/Icon.png. How do I get the contains of 'Url' then convert it into Strings(or Url) so my downloader will download it? This XML files is very long, it contains more then 100 files to download.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Try googling [`java jaxb simple example`](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+jaxb+simple+example&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&hl=en&client=safari)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a xml parser

ex. **JDOM**:

> JDOM is, quite simply, a Java representation of an XML document. JDOM
> provides a way to represent that document for easy and efficient
> reading, manipulation, and writing. It has a straightforward API, is a
> lightweight and fast, and is optimized for the Java programmer. It's
> an alternative to DOM and SAX, although it integrates well with both
> DOM and SAX.

- [jdom](http://www.jdom.org/)
- [woodstox](http://woodstox.codehaus.org/)
- [xom](http://xom.nu/)

and there are many others. just check if this is what you need to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I am sure, you must be knowing about OXM (Object XML Mapping). There are many ways of achieving what you want.

I would suggest you the easiest one. Ask your friend to generate a XSD(XML Schema Definition) for the XML file which contains all the URLs.

Then Write a simple java code to marshal the XML file which you have added above using `JAXBMarshaller` or `XMLBeans`.

You will get java objects corresponding to this XML and all the tags as properties for the java object.

After that you can simply use get method to get the values of the URL tags by just iterating through the list of properties :)

**EDIT** : You can also use SAX parser or DOM manipulation to extract the values, but I find the OXMs better.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I will ask him to generate a XSD file, Ty

Comment: That would make your life very easy :)

Answer (score 0):

I changed your xml to a better structure:

```
    <xml version="1.0"?>
      <Files>
        <File>
          <Url>lib/lwjgl.jar</Url>
          <DateCreated>2013-04-30T09:25:54.000Z</DateCreated>
          <Size>2389</Size>
        </File>
        <File>
          <Url>img/Icon.png</Url>
          <DateCreated>2013-05-21T12:26:15.000Z</DateCreated>
          <Size>56</Size>
        </File>
      </Files>
```

This can be associated to an xsd like the following:

```
    <xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified"     xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <xs:element name="Files">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="File" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
              <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                  <xs:element type="xs:string" name="Url"/>
                  <xs:element type="xs:dateTime" name="DateCreated"/>
                  <xs:element type="xs:short" name="Size"/>
                </xs:sequence>
              </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:schema>
```

Then you can, among many possibilities, generate the jaxb classes from the xsd, add them to your classpath.
This done you can marshall/unmarshall the xml extracting the url.
a very simple example for using jaxb is here:
http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/02/jaxb-generate-xml-xsd.html

It describes both class generation (easy case) and usage in a main().